# Finance Naming Policy ssms, Can't Create Tables error (ends in trigger)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

I am getting the following error when I try to create even basic tables in any database in ssms 2012:

Policy 'Finance Name' has been violated by 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\ACER-PC\DEFAULT\Databases\AdventureWorks2012\Tables\dbo.CustomersNew'.

This transaction will be rolled back.

Policy condition: '@Name LIKE 'fintbl%''

Policy description: ''

Additional help: '' : ''

Statement: 'create table CustomersNew (names int not null)
 ;'.

Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_syspolicy_dispatch_event, Line 65
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Is there any way to delete this Policy?  This version of SSMS is my own on my personal computer and was used for class only.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Figured it out, expand the Management folder, right click Policy Management, then click "disable".

Comment: Glad you found out the solution. Please answer your own question and accept that answer so that people will know the problem is solved.